# What is that tree?

Tags: identification

This is a tree that blooms in July and doesn't lose its leaves in winter. It is about 20 meters tall. Here are some pictures:

**Leaves**

[image: Leaves]

**Flowers**

[image: Flowers]

**Top**

[image: Top]

**Trunk and roots**

[image: Trunk and roots]

Can you help me identify it?

Comment: What location in the world

Comment: South of France

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks much like a Privet, so best guess is [Ligustrum lucidum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligustrum_lucidum) **Chinese privet / Glossy privet**, (and French language page [here](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligustrum_lucidum) that states the tree can reach 25m tall)

[image: Ligustrum lucidum]

[Image Link](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a8/LigustrumLucidumFlowers.jpg/640px-LigustrumLucidumFlowers.jpg)

**Tree Characteristics**

- Compact and Erect or Spreading with a High Canopy.
- Oval, Rounded or Umbrella Shape.
- Has Evergreen foliage.
- Height: 35 - 50 feet.
- Leaves Ovate, Glossy Dark Green, No Change, Evergreen.
- Flowers Showy. Fragrant White. Flowers in Spring or Summer. Has separate male and female flowers on the same tree (monoecious).
- Prolific, Black or Mostly Blue Drupe, Small (0.25 - 0.50 inches), fruiting in Fall, Winter or Summer.

Comment: I've never seen a tree form of this plant.  Wow.

Comment: @stormy I only see them to about 20ft tall in my neck of the woods, so 20M tall as the OPs tree had me second guessing. But it was the flowers in the photo that convinced me.

Comment: Totally the flowers!  I've never seen any tree form of this plant ever.  Many many hedges.  The flower is definitive.  Good job, renesis!