# tree id needed - evergreen,two opposing leaves

Tags: identification

Can you identify this tree?  It is in my backyard and might like to have it in other places as well. It is evergreen and grows very fast. This backyard is in zone 10a.    I have not seen any blooms or fruits.

Thanks

Pictures:

[image: leaves]

[image: trunk]

[image: full tree/shrub - ignore the branch going across] - The branch going between left and right does not belong to the tree in this question.

Comment: Hmm... what do you think @Stormy ? another [Privet](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/39775/what-is-that-tree/39778?noredirect=1#comment56450_39778) or maybe a Ficus?

Comment: break a leaf or scratch the bark: if white sticky sap comes out it is a ficus. has the right leaf shape and bark

Comment: ha ha ha, that is exactly what I thought until I got very distracted by the plastic.  Funny you.  I can't stand plastic in the landscape...arghhhh!  Go ahead and put that out there...I think you are right!

Comment: Ficus benjamina I reckon, but do the test - bend a leaf in half, if it oozes white sap, that's what it is.

Comment: This is absolutely a Privet, Ligustrum "something". As to whether or not it is a Ficus Benjamina: Look at those upward-thrusting shoots in the last of the 3 photos provided. That is very characteristic of privet.

Admittedly, I don't have a F. Benjamina to compare, so only ended up looking at pictures on computer, but those ficus plants don't seem to shoot upward like the privet will. BUT, what I can't explain is why no flowers or fruits. The privets around here are all just loaded with stinky flowers & hyper-fertile fruits (hate them)....perhaps this is some non-flowering variety???

Comment: No oozing white sap seen when breaking a leaf or a branch.

Comment: This tree does not seem to be invasive through roots, does not seem to flower, is evergreen and has zero to low litter. Unless it is toxic, invasive or the roots can uproot concrete, it is perfect as a poolside and for privacy. The foliage is quite dense and the tree grows fast (2-3 feet in one season). (caveat: I haven't been in this house for an entire 12 month period yet, but I remember tree had its leaves last December and January)

Comment: @Lorel C. - I hate them too! I've been fooled from a distance seeing them growing in riparian areas into thinking I'd spotted big clumps of elderberries! (You don't have to be very close before it becomes obvious...) They are definitely Invasive here in zone 10a, but if rpkrpk's tree is not flowering (all near me currently are), then perhaps there is some micro-environmental thing keeping it from doing so? If it doesn't fruit, then keep it I guess. Someone else should make the answer, as I am still thrown off by the lack of flowers & wouldn't be prepared to defend the assertion.

Answer (score 1):

Ligustrum Japonicum, the manager at a local nursery confirmed. The nursery does not sell these, but when I was there for some other reason, I noticed these trees in the property adjacent to the nursery and asked the nursery manager about it. He confirmed it and recommended that I not plant it because it can grow as a weed with seeds spread through birds.